# Swift let ... { in

Tags: swift, closures, rx-swift

I know this is probably a very basic question but it has been nagging at me for a while. Could someone explain what the idea of this `let` is? Or at least what it is commonly used for? I keep seeing let variables like:

```
let thisVar = ... { var1, var2, var3 in
    methods
}
```

This is an example from the RxRealmDataSources:

```
let dataSource = RxTableViewRealmDataSource<Lap>(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: PersonCell.self) {cell, ip, lap in
    cell.customLabel.text = "\(ip.row). \(lap.text)"
}
```

I am mostly confused about what `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` (or `cell`, `ip`, `lap` in the RxRealmDataSources example) are meant to do. Thanks!

Comment: google "trailing closure"

Comment: Please review the [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: Read the [language guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
let dataSource = RxTableViewRealmDataSource<Lap>(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: PersonCell.self) {cell, ip, lap in
    cell.customLabel.text = "\(ip.row). \(lap.text)"
}
```

This is instantiating a `RxTableViewRealmDataSource` where the third parameter of this initialization method is a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94). In this case, this closure is just a bit of code that you supply to the data source to tell it what to do when it's ready to configure a cell. In fact, we can actually look at the [source code for this `init` method](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealmDataSources/blob/beacaa6d4ffb0cc50ca1ef821caad74950d74201/Pod/Classes/RxTableViewRealmDataSource.swift#L48):

```
public init<CellType>(cellIdentifier: String, cellType: CellType.Type, cellConfig: @escaping TableCellConfig<E, CellType>) where CellType: UITableViewCell {
    self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
    self.cellFactory = {ds, tv, ip, model in
        let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: ip) as! CellType
        cellConfig(cell, ip, model)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Don't get lost in the details there, but just notice that it takes three parameters, of which the last parameter is a closure of type `TableCellConfig`. And this closure is "`@escaping`", meaning that it's a bit of code that will be called later (when the cell needs to be configured).

Note, this third parameter is called `cellConfig`, but your code snippet is using "trailing closure" syntax to make it more concise, whereby the last parameter, because it's a closure, can have its label omitted and the closure is just appended right after the initializer. This is described in the “Tailing Closures” section within [The Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94).

So, bottom line, this `let` is setting `dataSource` to be a  `RxTableViewRealDataSource` whose third parameter is a closure that will be called later, when the cell needs to be configured. And this closure, itself, has three parameters, `cell`, `ip`, and `lap`, that are passed to this closure when it's called. E.g. in your code snippet, your trailing closure uses the first parameter, `cell` to know which cell needs to be updated, and your closure is updating the label of the cell to show a string consisting of `ip.row` and `lap.text`. These are parameters to the closure because they won't be known until the closure is called later, when the cell needs to be presented.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating two unrelated things.  The method being invoked returns a value, and that is being assigned to the variable named before the `=`.  The block at the end is a trailing closure, which is the last parameter of the method call. The `var1, var2, var3 in` syntax is how parameters being passed to a closure are specified.